# Sails JS: res.view() not working from any of my controllers

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I'm new to Sails JS, and I've successfully built authentication with passport. After authenticating the user, res.send() works to send the user information but res.view() returns the following:

```
Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 Could not render view "/dashboard".  Tried locating view file @ "/Users/hackthievist/Projects/delivery-science-project/views/bad". Layout configured as "layouts/layout", so tried using layout @ "/Users/hackthievist/Projects/delivery-science-project/views/layouts/layout")
```

Here is my AuthController:

```
/**
 * AuthController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side actions for handling incoming requests.
 * @help        :: See https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/actions
 */

 const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = {

    login: function(req, res) {
        passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
            if((err) || (!user)) {
                return res.send({
                    message: info.message,
                    user
                });
            }

            req.logIn(user, (err) => {
                if(err) res.send(err);
                return res.view('dashboard');
            });
        })(req, res);
    },

    logout: function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    }

};
```

And here is my passport.js

```
const passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
    cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, cb) {
    User.findOne({ id }, function (err, user) {
        cb(err, users);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passportField: 'password'
}, function (username, password, cb) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        if (!user) return cb(null, false, { message: 'Username not found' });
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
            if (!res) return cb(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password'});
            let userDetails = {
                email: user.email,
                username: user.username,
                id: user.id
            };
            return cb(null, userDetails, { message: 'Login Successful' });
        });
    });
}));
```

I have also tried using res.view() from other controllers and it returns the same error. Please help.

Comment: This may not be the issue, but it seems a little strange that you are telling it to send 'dashboard', but the file is '/views/bad'.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting an error from `req.login`. I notice your code doesn't halt in case of an error:

```
req.login(user, (err) => {
    if(err) res.send(err);
    return res.view('dashboard');
});
```

But this would run `res.send` AND `res.view` in case of an error. You chould change it to something like:

```
req.login(user, (err) => {
    if(err) { return res.send(err); }
    return res.view('dashboard');
});
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, I would follow up on the fairly specific error message you have - as @streleckify points out, why is it looking for the file `views/bad`? Is this a partial from your layout file perhaps?

Comment: `res.send` sends headers, so it automatically halts. Turns out req.logIn was redundant, so I removed the entire block and have this

`login: function (req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      if ((err) || (!user)) {
        statusMessage = 'Wrong Credentials';
        return res.redirect('/login');
      }

res.redirect('/dashboard');

    })(req, res);

  }`